# Redirect all subdirectory child pages to subdirectory root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried to find the answer to the question above and have been unable to do so.  Most examples I've found are for redirecting all subdirectory child pages to the root, but not to the subdirectory's root.

For example, I want all http://domain.com/subdirectory/* to go to http://domain.com/subdirectory/ and have implemented the following redirect rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /subdirectory/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

I've also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdirectory/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Both scenarios above causes a redirect loop error when attempting to go to http://domain.com/subdirectory -- any ideas or suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.+` after directory name in your regex:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(subdirectory)/(.+)$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Otherwise `subdirectory/.*` also matches `/subdirectory/` and caused redirect loop.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this rule as it works on my Apache. For 500 you should check your Apache error.log and report the error here

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was not working at all, but this had:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdirectory/(.+)$ /subdirectory